# HTMLParser:Handling malformed start tag in HTML Documents

Tags: python, html-parsing

I am using the `HTMLParser` class in Python to parse a HTML doc. But, I am getting the error "malformed start tag" occasionally. Is there a way to handle this such that I just remove the malformed start tag and still parse the remaining document?

Comment: Use a parser like [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) which is happier with malformed input.

Comment: Have you got a short sample of a document that's failing?